# Verifying that a copy succeeded

Tags: shell, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to write a script that verifies if a copy succeeded or not.
Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
cp home/testing/present.txt home/testing/future.txt
   echo "Copy Code: $? - Successful"
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
   echo "Copy Code: $? - Unsuccessful"
fi
```

The "if" statement is not being initialized. How can resolve this? 
Thank You for your time.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`$?` refers to the last command:

```
#!/bin/sh
cp home/testing/present.txt home/testing/future.txt
   echo "Copy Code: $? - Successful"   # last command: cp
if [ $? != 0 ]; then                   # last command: echo
   echo "Copy Code: $? - Unsuccessful" # last command: [
fi
```

If you want to repeatedly work with the status of a specific command, just save the result in another variable:

```
#!/bin/sh
cp home/testing/present.txt home/testing/future.txt
status=$?
echo "Copy Code: $status - Successful"
if [ $status != 0 ]; then
   echo "Copy Code: $status - Unsuccessful"
fi
```

However, a better approach is to simply test the `cp` command in the first place:

```
if cp home/testing/present.txt home/testing/future.txt
then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Failure, exit status $?"
fi
```

Comment: Amazingly simple and elegant. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: In the first approach, it is better to put `status=$?` on the same line as the `cp ...` command to prevent any future changes from overriding what values goes into the `status` variable.

Answer (score 11):

Simplify, simplify, simplify:

```
#!/bin/sh
if cp home/testing/present.txt home/testing/future.txt; then
   echo "Copy Code: $? - Successful"
else
   echo "Copy Code: $? - Unsuccessful"
fi
```

If you want to test whether a command is successful, test the status with the `if` statement.

Remember that `$?` is the exit status of the last command executed.  It is like an extremely volatile global variable (in C or C++).
In your code, you run `echo` which clobbers the value in `$?` from the `cp` command.  If you need to explicitly capture `$?`, do so explicitly and immediately after the command whose status you need to capture:

```
cp home/testing/present.txt home/testing/future.txt
cp_status=$?
```

and then test `$cp_status` in the following code.

Comment: In the words of the great Ric Flair: "WOOOOOOOOOOOO"